# Logged in user information incorrectly dispalyed

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have created a page to update User profile. If I try to update a value of user with existing user, error is thrown as expected, however the variable `user.username` in `profile.html` shows the value I am trying to update. My query is why `{{ user.username }}` is picking up the incorrect value even though the save() method is not called.

[image]

profile.html

```
   <div class="content p-3">
            <div><img class="rounded-circle" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" width="100" height="100"></div>
            <div>{{ user.username }}</div>
            <div>{{ user.email }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-25">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Profile Info</legend>
                    {{ user_form | crispy }}
                    {{ profile_form | crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <input class="mt-3" type="submit" value="Update">
            </form>
        </div>
```

forms.py

```
  class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        email = forms.EmailField()
    
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['username', 'email']
    

    class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Profile
            fields = ['image']
```

views.py

```
    @login_required
    def profile(request):
        if (request.method == "POST"):
            user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
            profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                             request.FILES,
                                             instance=request.user.profile)
            if (user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid()):
                user_form.save()
                profile_form.save()
                messages.success(request, f"Your profile is updated successfully")
                return redirect("profile")
            else:
               messages.error(request, f"Failed to update profile")
        else:
            user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
            profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        return render(request, 'User/profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form}
```

Comment: Is this a custom user model or default one? Can you provide the model? If it's the default one you can use class [`UserChangeForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm) will do the job

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna This is default User model. I have created a Profile model which has a user attribute with OneToOneField.

Comment: Is the ModelForm updating the instance as part of the validation? Can you try logging/printing `request.user.username` before and after `user_form.is_valid()` is executed?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, The `request.user.username` is getting changed after `user_form.is_valid()`. Why is this happening. Can we avoid that.

Comment: In order to save the new details both the two forms need to be validated so if one form has a validation failure the save process won't happen(ex: empty fields), I used the same code in my project and that was the issue I faced

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna I got the issue as mentioned by Iain. This is a bug in django framework which is modifying the instance object during is_valid() function. This is not expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ModelForm updating the instance as part of validation is strange/unwanted behaviour, maybe you have found a "bug"

A work around would be to pass a copy of `request.user` using [`copy.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy) into the ModelForm so that any changes made as part of validation happen on the copy

```
user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=copy.copy(request.user))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)`,
your user_form update itself using the values received from front-end. In this case, username is 'newuser2'.

Since this username is taken, user_form.is_valid() returns false and below render function is returned:
`return render(request, 'User/profile.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form}`
Please note that this instance of user_form has username as "newuser2". Thats why you see username as "newuser2" instead of your current logged in user.

Apologies for the brevity, I'm learning to post answers.

Comment: The form will show the value which user filled. That behaviour is fine. However my question is that the user object within request is getting updated with newuser value despite save not called for that instance i.e. {{ user.username }} should have the value of logged in user since the update operation did not succeed.